# I have wrote two js scripts, both of them work but the problem is only the one placed second in the code will work

Tags: javascript

i am trying to develop an eCommerce website for the first time but in here i wrote two scripts

As you can see in the pictures, it works well but only the one placed second will work on the website,
[first image the dropdown script works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LofiD.png)
[second one the scroll finction works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBdk4.jpg)

```js
//show dropdowns//

function myFunction(a) {
    a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle("show");
}

//click anywhere to hide dropdown//
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};



window.onscroll = function () {
    myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("tph").className = "scrolled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("tph").className = "header_top";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use the same ***name*** for both functions?

Comment: omg thank you i didn't evenn notice i was using the same function name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the name of one of your functions to prevent overwriting.

> JavaScript supports overriding not overloading, meaning, that if you define two functions with the same name, the last one defined will override the previously defined version and every time a call will be made to the function, the last defined one will get executed.

```js
function myFunction(a) {
    a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle("show");
}

//click anywhere to hide dropdown//
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};



window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction2();
};

function myFunction2() {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("tph").className = "scrolled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("tph").className = "header_top";
    }
}
```